# How to re-read the Windows Phone SDK user agreement?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8.1

I installed the Windows Phone development environment on a Surface Pro from...

- -> http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk
- -> Windows Phone 8.1 development tools
- -> If you don’t have Visual Studio 2013, you can install Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows, which includes Update 2, using this download link:
- -> Download(up to 1.1 MB, English)

However, I forgot to read carefully the user agreement that is displayed on screen when I was installing it. How can I re-read the agreement?

Answer (score 0):

In the help menu select about.  There should be link to view the license agreement in the top right corner of the dialog that opens